# Implementing isLoggedIn() function in Angular with oidc-client in *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

Goal: I am attempting to hide and show a Loggin and Logout button in an Angular app using IdentityServer4 and oidc client.

Problem: The response from my isLoggedIn function returns undifined before it returns true and the *ngIf never shows the Logout button or hides the Login button.  See code:

app.componenet.html:

```
<span>
      <button *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()" mat-button (click)="login()">Login</button>
      <button *ngIf="isLoggedIn()" mat-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</span>
```

app.componenet.ts:

```
    isLoggedIn(){
        console.log('isLoggedIn -this._authService.isLoggedIn():',
          this._authService.isLoggedIn());
        this._authService.isLoggedIn();
      }
```

auth.service.ts

```
isLoggedIn(): boolean{
    return this._user && this._user.access_token && !this._user.expired;
  }
```

in auth.service.ts i set the user object like this:

```
 this._userManager = new UserManager(config);
    this._userManager.getUser().then(user =>{
      if(user && !user.expired){
        this._user = user;
      }
```

console.log output:
[image]

What I've tried:

1. I tried playing around with my version of oidc-client, switching
   between leatest and 1.4.1 and making sure that they match in
   package.json and my oidc-login-redirect.html file.
2. Turning the auth.service.ts isLoggedIn function into a promise isLoggedIn() and calling it directly from *nfIf using an async pipe

auth.service.ts
    Promise{
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve(this._user && this._user.access_token && !this._user.expired);
        });
      }

app.component.html

```
  <button *ngIf="!this._authService.isLoggedIn() | async" mat-button (click)="login()">Login</button>
  <button *ngIf="this._authService.isLoggedIn() | async" mat-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

Neither of these things has worked, and the promise attempt caused google chrome to hang up:
[image]

Comment: I don't think you've included enough code to solve this problem.  There is no reason to have to wrap your code in a promise or use `async`.  The delay must occur because of whatever is setting `this._user`.  This makes sense since in *oidc_client* you have to call `manager.getUser()` which returns a promise.  So there are multiple states, *unknown*, *loggedin*, *loggedout*. Make sure you take that under consideration.

Comment: @DanielGimenez I added the code that sets this._user, if you have any suggestions on what is missing please let me know.

Comment: I'd expect `authService` to hold a Behavior Subject or such, and emit a value when the user logged in. this would make everything a lot cleaner in your component where a local variable cam be set on `ngOnInit` and your template would only be based on that local variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling signinRedirectCallback in your Angular app somewhere (as opposed to a separate html page that lives outside your SPA), it is likely that your code setting this.user is being called prior to the signin callback bring invoked.

You should subscribe to addUserLoaded on UserManager and set the user in your auth service from in the handler of that as well. That way your user will always be up to date.

If the code above was copy/pasted from your source, your app.component isLoggedIn is not returning the value from the auth service, it is just calling isLoggedIn on the auth service but not returning the value.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did have the signinRedirectCallback in a separate file.  The issue was caused by the fact that I simply forgot to return the value :( .  Its not a good idea to code after a fool days work, putting kids to bed, and on only a few hours sleep and too much coffee.  Thanks.